# Black blank area problem at the place of navigation bar when input keyboard appears

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[image: SS]When the keyboard appears, there is a black blank area where the navigation bar appears. The sticky immersive mode is working, but is there a way to get rid of that black area? Maybe making that bar transparent?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of it? It will help a lot.

Comment: @SiAce I added it now